# Download a list of photos from CSV

Tags: python-3.x, image, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

I tried to download a list of photos from the CSV file. I want to save all photos from the link list column and save it to the folder with the same name as the link list column.

Expected:
[image: Example how it should look]

CSV file:

```
    1   a-Qc01o78E                                          a-rrBuci0w                                          a-qj8s5nlM                                          a-Cwciy2zx
0   2   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/9f13389c/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/8852c424/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/650d84fd/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/a99f9e52/big.jpg
1   3   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/f0adc019/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/c434624c/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/bed9125c/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/2d0b7a67/big.jpg
2   4   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/8844627a/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/edda4ec4/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/3283fe57/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/1f6425e5/big.jpg
3   5   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/eeb8b78a/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/6cdcbbf7/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/f64ca040/big.jpg    https://uvd.yupoo.com/ven-new/22259049_oneTrue.jpg
4   6   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/9c3e9a92/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/ea257725/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/64b5a57f/big.jpg    https://uvd.yupoo.com/ven-new/22257899_oneTrue.jpg
5   7   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/baaf8945/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/e9cc7392/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/753418b5/big.jpg    https://uvd.yupoo.com/ven-new/22257619_oneTrue.jpg
6   8   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/a325f44a/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/671be145/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/1742a09d/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/c9d0aa0f/big.jpg
7   9   https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/367cf72a/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/ae7f1b1b/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/d0ef54ed/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/2d0905df/big.jpg
8   10  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/3fcacff3/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/c4ea9b1e/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/683db958/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/3b065995/big.jpg
9   11  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/c7de704a/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/92abc9ea/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/bd1083db/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/a9086d26/big.jpg
10  12  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/fc481727/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/a49c94df/big.jpg
11  13  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/1e0e0e10/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/62580909/big.jpg
12  14  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/934b423e/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/74b81853/big.jpg
13  15  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/adf878b2/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/5ad881c3/big.jpg
14  16  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/59dc1203/big.jpg    https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/3cd676ac/big.jpg
15  17  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/6d8eb080/big.jpg
16  18  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/9a027ada/big.jpg
17  19  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/bdeaf1b5/big.jpg
18  20  https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/1f293683/big.jpg
```

```
def get_photos(x):
    with requests.Session() as c:
        df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Lukasz\\Desktop\\PROJEKTY PYTHON\\W TRAKCIE\\YUOPOO SCRAPER\\FF_data_frame.csv")
        NazwyKolum = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Lukasz\\Desktop\\PROJEKTY PYTHON\\W TRAKCIE\\bf3_strona.csv")
        c.get('https://photo.yupoo.com/')
        c.headers.update({'referer': 'https://photo.yupoo.com/'})
        URLS=(df[NazwyKolum['LINKS'][x]])      #.to_string(index=False))
        print(URLS) #prints a list of links. Example https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/650d84fd/big.jpg, https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/bed9125c/big.jpg
        #proxies = {'https': 'http://45.77.76.254:8080'}
        res = c.get(URLS,timeout=None)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            return res.content

try:
    for x in range(2,50):
        with open("C:\\Users\\Lukasz\\Desktop\\PROJEKTY PYTHON\\W TRAKCIE\\YUOPOO SCRAPER\\"+str(x)+'NAZWAZDECIA.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(get_photos(x))
except:
    print("wr")
```

To be honest, I do not how to handle it anymore, I wast a lot of time with no progress. Thank you, guys.

Comment: What seems to be the issue ? Are you getting an error or is it doing something unexpected ?

Comment: No connection adapters were found for '0 [...]'

Comment: Please don't include images of spreadsheets - they are very difficult to parse. As you have a CSV, please click `edit` under your question and paste the actual CSV.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, os

df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

def create_directory(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

def download_save(url, folder):
    create_directory(folder)
    res = requests.get(url)
    with open(f'{folder}/{url.split("/")[-2]}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(res.content)

for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
    for url in df[col].tolist():
        print(url)
        if str(url).startswith("http"):
            download_save(url, col)
```

The above code creates column names as directories and downloads the images and saves it with unique name in the url.

Here `a.csv` is as follows:

```
a-Qc01o78E,a-rrBuci0w,a-qj8s5nlM,a-Cwciy2zx
https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/9f13389c/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/8852c424/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/650d84fd/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/a99f9e52/big.jpg
https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/f0adc019/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/c434624c/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/bed9125c/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/2d0b7a67/big.jpg
https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/8844627a/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/edda4ec4/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/3283fe57/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/1f6425e5/big.jpg
https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/eeb8b78a/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/6cdcbbf7/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/f64ca040/big.jpg,https://uvd.yupoo.com/ven-new/22259049_oneTrue.jpg
https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/9c3e9a92/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/ea257725/big.jpg,https://photo.yupoo.com/ven-new/64b5a57f/big.jpg,https://uvd.yupoo.com/ven-new/22257899_oneTrue.jpg
```

Comment: hi!. It works almost now, but after downloading all links from the column there is a message: 'Invalid URL 'nan': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://nan?'. Thank you

Comment: For `nan` you can reject the urls